# How to handle Element is not visisble error in selenium while working with dropdown?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

While creating automation scripts I encountered `'Element not visible'` error while trying to select the option from drop-down list.
HTML code of drop down . [Drop-down HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewgos.png)

Comment: what you have tried ? to select drop down pls mention....

Comment: Please paste your code into the question.

Comment: It is easier to help you, if you paste your HTML as code not as screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example in Java (similar in other programming languages) using FirefoxDriver:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='cfr_eventtype_i']"));
Select select = new Select(we);
select.selectByVisibleText("Meeting");
```